# How to subtract from a slider each 60 sec c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to get a stamina slider its work like energie each 60 seconds it subtract 1 from the slider but at the moment my script wait for 60 seconds and the it subtract all stamina points of the slider at once
How can i do this only work once every 60 seconds and subtract 1 from the slider each 60 seconds? 
This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class staminatimer : MonoBehaviour {
public Slider mySlider;





// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{


}

IEnumerator Start ()
{
    //Wait for 60 secs.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (60);
    subtractstam ();

}

private void subtractstam()
{
    mySlider.value -= 5;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is put that code in a `while` loop so that it will repeat forever until you want it to stop.

```
bool keepSubstracting = true;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    //Wait for 60 secs.
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(60);
    while (keepSubstracting)
    {
        yield return waitTime;
        subtractstam();
    }
}

void stop()
{
    keepSubstracting = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, supposing your slider has a max value > 5 and only one script is attached.

```
void Start ()
{
    mySlider.maxValue = 100 ; // If not already set in the inspector
    StartCoroutine( subtractStamPeriodically() ) ;    
}

private IEnumerator subtractStamPeriodically()
{
    WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds( 60 ) ;
    while( true )
    {
        yield return wait  ;
        subtractStam();
    }
}

private void subtractStam()
{
    mySlider.value -= 5;
}
```

Comment: Does this works every 60 sec? Since you use it in `Start()`.

Comment: Yes it will, the Start method will start the inifnite coroutine which will wait 60 seconds, substract the stamina and loop again.